# Is 32x equivalent to 320%?

Tags: percentages

Ok, I know that might be a silly question, even completely dumb. 
I'm not good at maths and this question came to my mind :

I use 2 pixel softwares, in the first you can choose the export quality by getting the image bigger by multiplying the size. In the other software it's made by percentages. So I wanted to know if the equivalent is this simple -> the image x 32 is the same than 320% its size.

Thanks in advance

Comment: $100\% = \times 1$, so $3200\% = \times 32$

Comment: Ok, thank you ! That's a question answered for my little mind :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $32\cdot x$ is equivalent to $3200\%$ of $x$. Two decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

No.

x $32 = 32×100 $%$ = 3200 $%